# How to understand a note for the distribution of the sample for confidence interval?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, nonparametric

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Definition) for  confidence interval, there is a note for the distribution of the sample:

> Note that here **$Pr_{θ,φ}$ need not refer to an explicitly given
> parameterised family of distributions**, although it often does. Just
> as the random variable $X$ notionally corresponds to other possible
> realizations of $x$ from the same population or from the same version
> of reality, **the parameters $(θ, φ)$ indicate that we need to
> consider other versions of reality in which the distribution of $X$
> might have different characteristics**.

1. I was wondering how to understand "$Pr_{θ,φ}$ need not refer to an
   explicitly given parameterised family of distributions"? What is
   $Pr_{θ,φ}$ like when it need not refer to an explicitly given
   parameterised family of distributions?
2. How shall I understand "the parameters $(θ, φ)$ indicate that we
   need to  consider other versions of reality in which the
   distribution of $X$  might have different characteristics"? What is
   the distribution of $X$ like when it might have different
   characteristics?

Comment: Perhaps I'm not following your question but I think the way that you'e worded it the answers practically tautological.  When the parameters are different, then they're different.  When the characteristics of X are different, X is different.  Feel free to imagine whatever world you can.